# Create multiple behavior subjects in one service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am trying to hit multiple services after logging into my app. I have created a service file and in that there is a function that will hit multiple apis and initialize behavior subjects. But what is happening is that all the behavior subjects are getting initialized with same api data. How can i ensure that a particular api data gets into the required behvior subject variable. Here is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { IStatusRepository } from '../interfaces/istatus-repository';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IZone } from '../interfaces/izone';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SystemStorageService {

    statusReposDatasource: BehaviorSubject<IStatusRepository[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    zonesDatasource: BehaviorSubject<IZone[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    statusRepos = this.statusReposDatasource.asObservable();
    zones = this.zonesDatasource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private http:HttpClient
    ) {}

    setStatusRepos() {
        this.http.get<IStatusRepository[]>(`${environment.url}/StatusRepositories`).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.statusReposDatasource.next(res);
        });

        this.http.get<IZone[]>(
            `${environment.url}/Zones`
        ).subscribe(val => {
            console.log(val);
            this.zonesDatasource.next(val);
        });
    }
}
```

results

[image]

Comment: console.log in both api calls gives me response of statusrepository in both api calls. which is wrong as in my second api call i need to get zones

Comment: So you have two different request to two different API endpoints that give you the same response?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your back-end

Comment: This is strange. Can you confirm that data returned in HTTP is different in your browser's network tab?

Comment: @martin yes. Both api returned be different data when i check from swagger. but here when called give same response

Comment: @AkshayRana confirmed data is differnet

Comment: Please post screenshot of network tab results.

Comment: @kvetis edited question with results screenshot

Comment: If your BE really returns different data for those request, maybe you have some cache on the FE with old data?

Comment: @ahsannissar Thats the screenshot for console, not network tab.

Comment: @AkshayRana see on the top zones and status repos api's calls are being called. They both return diferent results when opened in another tab. I thought console is showing enough data

Comment: I solved this by making api calls in separate functions and then calling both functions separately. Not sure why it was not working in same function

Comment: In the screenshot, there is the log. Post devtools network results.